# Can I play games off a sd card?

Tags: games, playonlinux, chromebook, sd-card

So I have ubuntu 14.04 running xfce4. I was planning on getting a 64 gb sd card to play games on it. I have a Dell chromebook. I just wanted to know if it was possible to download games such as league of legends, rocket league, cs go on the sd and play it on the chromebook. I already have minecraft running on the system's memory. If that was possible, can you please explain how to do it in a step by step process or send me a link to a video? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to ***not*** try to do this. SD cards are [notoriously slow](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/1wsv2t/can_i_run_games_off_a_class_10_microsd/) (although experiences vary), with a max of 312 MB/s for the highest class. Compare this to the max of 6 Gb/s for a hard drive.

At the very least, you will need to have a Class 10 or UHS-1 SD card, which are *not* cheap. The SD from your phone won't cut it.

Add this to the fact that Chromebooks are very well known to be lacking in performance, I'd be surprised if your games will even be able to run.

---

With that in mind, take this advice with a grain of salt.

1. Begin by inserting your SD card and making a note of where it mounts.
2. Download [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) and [symlink your wineprefix](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-10841-PoL_Directory_Location.html) to your SD card.
3. Use PlayOnLinux as you normally would. Games should automatically install to the SD card.

Comment: Shoud i get a different memory card then? Like a usb stick or something? What would make the games work best, or is there nothing i can do?

Comment: @Khang: You might have better luck with a USB 3.0 flash drive, but I would just get a full on computer for gaming. It's more trouble than it's worth to get it working on a Chromebook.

Comment: SD cards have become cheaper since this answer was posted. UHS-1 cards with transfer rates up to 100MBS are easily accessible. Additionally depending on the game most data may be loaded into ram. Wouldn't play AAA shooters this way, but should be fine for age of empires etc...